# PHP Variable not being set/declared/called correctly?

Tags: php, variables

I have part of a PHP script that's behaving odd for me. The below loop grabs the highest value from the `builds` array - which is a bunch of integers in a random order.  It grabs the highest value as expected, no problems there.

```
$highest = $builds[0];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($builds); $i++) {
        if ($builds[$i] > $highest) {
            $highest = $builds[$i];
    }
}
```

The problem is when I try to use `$highest` after the loop. (`file_get_html` is part of the simple_html_dom library - I use it fine in other parts of the script - it's not an issue.)

```
$html = file_get_html("http://www.blah.com/builds/" . $highest);
//timeout msg on browser
```

This ends up timing out. Chrome comes back with "Error 101: The connection was reset".
Firefox comes back with a similar, "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."

I've played around a bit, and best I can tell is that `$highest` isn't being set or called correctly somehow.

If I assign the variable manually, `file_get_html` works fine and returns data as expected.
I.E. If I make my script looks like this.

```
$highest = $builds[0];
    for ($i=0; $i < count($builds); $i++) {
        if ($builds[$i] > $highest) {
            $highest = $builds[$i];
    }
}

$highest = 20;  //I understand the loop is useless because of this
                //but I've been running it to make sure it's not the issue.

$html = file_get_html("http://www.blah.com/builds/" . $highest);
//now this returns data
```

Why does manually assigning the variable work, but setting it in the loop doesnt?
I've put in `prints` and `var_dumps` along the way to make sure the variable is being set correctly, and it appears to be.   Mind boggled.

Comment: whats the output of var_dump($highest) after loop?

Comment: try an `$highest = intval($highest);` after the loop.

Comment: @Bernhard - the result is `string '20' (length=2)`    @Chris, no dice.  Forgot to mention I also tried doing (string) to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Since the php [max()](http://php.net/max) function can take an array, a simpler version is

```
$highest=max($builds);
$html = file_get_html("http://www.blah.com/builds/" . $highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Giving this a test, all seems to work.

```
$builds = array(10, 5, 6, 9, 22, 54, 33, 72, 9);
$highest = $builds[0];
for ($i=0; $i < count($builds); $i++) {
    if ($builds[$i] > $highest) {
    $highest = $builds[$i];
    }
}

echo $highest;
```

Echoing $highest outputs 72, which is the highest number in the array. What type of array is $builds, what is the var_dump of the $builds array?

Comment: $builds var_dump = array (size=18)
  0 => string '4' (length=1)
  1 => string '16' (length=2)
  2 => string '8' (length=1)
  3 => string '2' (length=1)
  4 => string '14' (length=2)
  5 => string '12' (length=2)
  6 => string '11' (length=2)
  7 => string '10' (length=2)
  8 => string '9' (length=1)
  9 => string '1' (length=1)
  10 => string '7' (length=1)
  11 => string '17' (length=2)
  12 => string '13' (length=2)
  13 => string '5' (length=1)
  14 => string '3' (length=1)
  15 => string '15' (length=2)
  16 => string '1' (length=1)
  17 => string '0' (length=1)